# Ошибка при отправке сообщения через SMTP. Ruby. Gem Pony

Tags: ruby, gems

Возникает ошибка:

> ```
> /home/fucc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/pony-1.11/lib/pony.rb:250:in `block in build_mail': undefined method `body' for Pony:Module (NoMethodError)
> ```

Код для отправки:

```
def place
# Актуальный заказ
Pony.mail(:to => StoreApplication::Admin.email, 
            :from => "My store <mail@gmail.com>",
            :via => :smtp,
            :via_options => {
            adress:             'smtp.gmail.com',
            port:               '587',
            user_name:          'mail@gmail.com',
            password:           '###########',
            authentication:     :plain,
            domain:             "mail.google.com" },
            subject: "New order", body: "Check your admin panel")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли с решением на англоязычной версии сайта.
Ссылка на ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410357/error-when-send-mail-with-gem-pony-on-ruby
Финальный вариант кода:

```
def place
  Pony.mail(
    to: StoreApplication::Admin.email,
    from: 'My store <mail@gmail.com>',
    via: :smtp,
    via_options: {
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: '587',
      user_name: 'mail@gmail.com',
      password: '###########',
      authentication: :plain,
      domain: 'mail.google.com'
    },
    subject: 'New order',
    body: 'Check your admin page'
  )
end
```